# Looking for suggestions to reorder images in a user interface

Tags: java, xml, image, swing, jlist

I'm building an app that lets a user select a folder, the app then collects all of the images in that folder and allows the user to add captions and descriptions.  Essentially an interface that generates XML that drives a Flash photo gallery.

I'm now looking at various ways to provide some way for the user to rearrange those images in a different order.  I'm leaning toward some window of thumbs that allow drag and drop functionality, but...
1 - I'm a total Java noob so this is beyond my skill set today.  Though I am willing to tackle it if...
2 - Is this a good GUI user friendly approach?  Are there other methods that will provide a better user experience?

Essentially, I'm looking for ideas, a kind of what have you seen and used that is elegant and easy to use that provides this functionality.

If there are code examples that can be added, that would be perfect...

Comment: @Hov  Good call, up-voted, noise deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider

- using a JList which is built to easily display images and would allow drag & drop functionality with a minimum of coding.
- For creating the XML, perhaps try JAXB, although I would consider this to be a bit more than "basic" Java.

Comment: Thanks!!  I will look at JList.  The XML methods are already completed, I'm using DOM for that.  But I will also look at JAXB and see if it may benefit me to switch.

Comment: Ok, I found the basics in this demo: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DragListDemo.htm) that was posted as an answer to almost the same question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804361/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-inside-jlist)...  And I thought I did enough searching, I guess I needed to know specifically that JList was what I wanted.